# Working with incoming WS in console

Tags: javascript, websocket

So this is what I could find on the page I want to work on:
https://gyazo.com/2ba7093bc8807646e0cc3f90b3ff8b84

I want to work with a specific incoming WS-message, but I am struggling with finding a solution to use it in console and with js. As you guys probably understand this is not my site, and I have never had any problems with this before.

Thank you in advance